# HTML/CSS: Layout Issues

Tags: css, html, footer

Basically I'm trying to create a simple webpage template which would contain 3 rows. The first being the header which contains two columns, the second just being the mainbody and then the last being a footer.

Coding wise i'm doing this kind of layout

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <header>
        </header>
        <div id="col2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div="mainbody"></div>
    <footer></footer>
```

Basically the trouble I'm having now is in regards to the first row with the two columns. Basically I have a picture in the first one and a bunch of buttons on the second one. Ideally what I would like is to have the header at 100% width so it fits the screen and the contents of the first column stick to the left and the buttons to the right. With the blank space left inbetween the two. So the contents stick to the sides so to speak.
At the moment I'm using `float:left` on CSS for the first column, I've been messing around with float/align/position but I can't seem to get anything to work.

So any advice on that I would appreciate it.

I also had another question in regards to the footer, basically I have no idea how to even go about doing it. So just asking if possible and guidance where to look.

So for the footer I was wondering if it would be possible for it, if in between the footer and the browser x-axis there's white space it fits to the screen and the body would strech. Because as of now my body is only at the height of the contents within. So basically general advice on CSS to help implement the style so it fits to the screen.

Comment: Post css code too, or create dabblet to start work with

Comment: May be the problem in mystypo? `<div="mainbody">`

Comment: can your post the picture of your desired result and css how did u try it........

Answer (score 0):

Header with 2 columns

```
<div id="header">
<div id="column1" style="float:left;">Image</div>
<div id="column2" style="float:left;">Buttons</div>
</div>
```

Now add desired margin-left to second column div. It will create space in between 2 columns

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="wrapper">
     <header>
       <div id="column1" style="float:left;">Image</div>
       <div id="column2" style="float:left;">Buttons</div>
      </header>

   <div class="mainbody">
     Content
   </div>

<footer></footer>
```

Use this

Answer (score 0):

It is simple structure that can be created as follows ([**Here is DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/naveenksh/K2pwc/))

HTML is

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <header><img src='http://www.topnews.in/files/facebook-yahoo.jpeg' height=200 />
        </header>
        <div id="col2"><input type=Button value ="button 1" /><br><input type=Button value ="button 1" /><br><input type=Button value ="button 1" /><br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div="mainbody">mainbody
    </div>
    <footer></footer>
</div>
```

And CSS will be

```
#header{overflow:auto}
header{float:left}
#col2{float:right}
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thanks for the response, as I was trying to do via float:left/rights. Your demo showed it me it must have been something wrong elsewhere, Turns out because I was using the display:box it wasn't working. So a simple changed to display:block made it work.